# Ошибка при установке MySQL как исправить?

Tags: mysql

Ошибка при установке MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: А с какими параметрами подключаетесь к базе?

Comment: Я навичок MySQL

Comment: Юзер, пароль, хост и и.д?

Comment: Не могу установить пароль пользователя root
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'вашпароль'

Ошибка
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Comment: Ваше соединение не использует пароль. (using password:NO)

Comment: Как мне правильно установить пароль пользователя root?

Comment: mysqladmin -u root -p